# Select behaving differently with Dataset and List

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, dataset, chemistry

I have just encountered what I would term an unexpected disagreement in behaviour between `Dataset` and `List`. Consider the following:

```
ClearAll[dat];
dat = Dataset[{
    <|"sml" -> "CCSCCSP(=S)(OCC)OCC", "pur" -> "A"|>,
    <|"sml" -> "NC(=O)C=3C(=O)[C@@]4(O)C(O)=C2C(=O)c1c(O)cccc1[C@@](C)(O)[C@H]2[C@H](O)[C@H]4[C@@H](C=3O)N(C)C", "pur" -> "D"|>,
    <|"sml" -> "CN1C[C@@H](C[C@@H]2c3cccc4ncc(C[C@@H]12)c34)C(=O)N[C@@]8(O[C@]7(O)N([C@@H](Cc5ccccc5)C(=O)N6CCC[C@H]67)C8=O)C(C)C", "pur" -> "A"|>
}];

ClearAll[tmp1, tmp2];

(* Choose all the rows whose SMILES are parsed as proper molecules. *)
tmp1 = dat // (Query[Select[Key["sml"] /* Molecule /* MoleculeQ]] /* Quiet);

(* Convert the dataset to a list, then choose the rows that can be parsed correctly. *)
tmp2 = dat // (
    Query[All, Values] /* Normal /*
    Select[First /* Molecule /* MoleculeQ] /*
    Quiet
);

tmp1
(* Failure[Molecule, <|"MessageTemplate" :> MessageName[Molecule, "aromat"], "MessageParameters" -> {{7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 17}}|>] *)

tmp2
(*
{
    {"CCSCCSP(=S)(OCC)OCC", "A"},
    {"NC(=O)C=3C(=O)[C@@]4(O)C(O)=C2C(=O)c1c(O)cccc1[C@@](C)(O)[C@H]2[C@H](O)[C@H]4[C@@H](C=3O)N(C)C", "D"},
    {"CN1C[C@@H](C[C@@H]2c3cccc4ncc(C[C@@H]12)c34)C(=O)N[C@@]8(O[C@]7(O)N([C@@H](Cc5ccccc5)C(=O)N6CCC[C@H]67)C8=O)C(C)C", "A"}
}
*)
```

In other words, in the case of `tmp2`, Mathematica evaluated the test as successful for every line in the list, in spite of the `Failure` message that would have been printed in the absence of the `Quiet` function.

But in the case of `tmp1`, Mathematica decided to abort the computation as soon as it encountered the failure and not return the entire `Dataset`.

In this behaviour intended?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either move the `Quiet` **inside** the body of `Query`, as in

```
Query[Select[Quiet[MoleculeQ[Molecule[#sml]]] &]][dat]
```

[image]

or use the `FailureAction` option for `Query`:

```
Query[Select[MoleculeQ[Molecule[#sml]] &], FailureAction -> None][dat]
```

[image]

But returning a `Failure` when encountering a message seems to be the default behavior for `Query`.

Answer (score 3):

The error messages comes from different parts in the two examples.

Consider the first part of the example with tmp1:

```
dat // (Query[Select[Key["sml"]]]) // FullForm
```

This query returns an empty dataset. I am not sure but I think the Select is the culprit.

On the other hand, the first part of tmp2 works:

```
t=dat // (Query[All, Values]/*Normal)
```

But the test in Select screws up. Consider the Select with an additional Print statement and traditional style:

```
Select[t , (Print["Inp=", #]; MoleculeQ[Molecule[First[#]]]) &]
```

If this test is done on the third element of "t" it throws the error mentioned above. We can test this by:

```
Molecule[First[{"CN1C[C@@H](C[C@@H]2c3cccc4ncc(C[C@@H]12)c34)C(=O)N[C@@]\
8(O[C@]7(O)N([C@@H](Cc5ccccc5)C(=O)N6CCC[C@H]67)C8=O)C(C)C", "A"}]]
```

[image: ![]

Even if an error is thrown, the result still has the Head "Molecule" and "MoleculeQ" returns "True":

```
MoleculeQ[
 Molecule[First[{"CN1C[C@@H](C[C@@H]2c3cccc4ncc(C[C@@H]12)c34)C(=O)N[\
C@@]8(O[C@]7(O)N([C@@H](Cc5ccccc5)C(=O)N6CCC[C@H]67)C8=O)C(C)C", 
    "A"}]]]

(* True *)
```

Therefore, tmp2 gives a result.

Comment: `This query returns an empty dataset. I am not sure but I think the Select is the culprit.` We should expect an empty dataset for this, no? After all, `Key["sml"]` by itself is not a predicate. It becomes one when composed with the other two functions: `Key["sml"] /* Molecule /* MoleculeQ`. As regards the point about the head `Molecule`, I get the same results when I replace `MoleculeQ` with `FailureQ`.